# Array of years, months and weeks working but week 01 of year showing incorrecltly

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have an array of years, months and weeks.

```
//Returns an array containing the years, months and week numbers between two dates
function year_month($start_date, $end_date)
{
    $begin = new DateTime( $start_date );
    $end = new DateTime( $end_date);
    $end->add(new DateInterval('P1W')); //Add 1 week to include the end date as a week
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1W'); //Add 1 week
    $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
    $aResult = array();
    foreach ( $period as $dt )
    {
        $aResult[$dt->format('Y')][$dt->format('M')][] = "W".$dt->format('W');
    }

    return $aResult;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r(year_month("25-11-2013","26-01-2014"));
echo '</pre>';
```

it outputs the following:

```
   Array
 (
   [2013] => Array
    (
        [Nov] => Array
            (
                [0] => W48
            )

        [Dec] => Array
            (
                [0] => W49
                [1] => W50
                [2] => W51
                [3] => W52
                [4] => W01
            )

    )

[2014] => Array
    (
        [Jan] => Array
            (
                [0] => W02
                [1] => W03
                [2] => W04
                [3] => W05
            )

    )

)
```

Notice that w01 is in the Dec array instead of the January array. I assume this is because Monday is the start of each week and in this case Monday is the 30th of December. Any ideas on how to get around this? In fact I am not sure what to do with border cases in general. If a week starts in one month but ends in another it should not be inserted into both months I would rather it be in the month in which it ends. But not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the thursday in the week of the starting date as the starting point, before adding weeks. The thursday will always be in the correct month (since that's what we use to decide if we're going to have week 53 or week 1 in the last week of December). If that thursday is in January, you're going to get W1 and January, if it's in December, you're going to get W53 and December.

If you want the month the week ends each time, use the sunday as the starting point instead.

Comment: Are you saying use thursday or sunday as the starting point in my dates or as the first day of the week in the php date function somehow?

Comment: Ok I see its the dates, trouble is I am using this array to create a gantt chart based on weeks and the user could choose to start on any date.

Comment: So what do you want to do if they start on the date that's in the wrong part of the week? If they want to start at 30. december in a week that's really in january? You can use strtotime("thursday this week") to get the thursday in a particular week (send in the timestamp as the second argument to do it for any week you have a date in).

Comment: hmm then it should probably just go in January.

Comment: you got an example of that?

Comment: var_dump(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('thursday this week', strtotime('2013-12-30'))));

Answer (score 0):

You assume right, week "belongs" to month in which week start date is, so your output is correct.

If you wish to set month to last day in week, this can be accomplished with [`setISODate()`](http://php.net/datetime.setisodate.php) method:

```php
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    $dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'), 7);
    $aResult[$dt->format('Y')][$dt->format('M')][] = "W".$dt->format('W');
}
```

But this will now work for every week that has dates in 2 different months, W05 is now in February.

**[Demo](https://eval.in/74330)**

Comment: .. or just add weeks, that are in 2 months, to both months. [Demo](https://eval.in/74360)